# From table of discrete joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to read the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ and $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ --- Durrett 1.4.2

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation

This is Durrett $3^{rd}$ Example 1.4.2, I understand most of it but I am stuck in the end. This example is designed to show that $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$ does not necessarily imply $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

To show this, he provided a table of discrete joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ as follows:

[image]

where  $a>0$, $b>0$ and $c\geq 0$, and $2a+2b+c=1$.

**This gives me the first question:**

> I understand he is making the total probability being $1$, and each
>   single probabilities non-negative. Then we only need $a,b,c\geq 0$,
>   but why he made $a,b>0$ and $c\geq0$ instead?

It is easy to see $\mathbb{E}(XY)=0=\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$ because $X$ and $Y$ are symmetrically distributed about $0$, so $\mathbb{E}X=0$ and $\mathbb{E}Y=0$ which imply that $\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y=0$ and the table is arranged such that $xy\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ for all $x,y$, so $\mathbb{E}(XY)=0$.

However, to prove the dependence, he said

> They are not independent since $$\mathbb{P}(X=1, Y=1)=0\neq ab=\mathbb{P}(X=1)\mathbb{P}(Y=1).$$

**This gives me the second confusion:**

> How did he know the probability of $X$ and $Y$ themselves? The table is joint distribution, right?

Did he actually refer that $\mathbb{P}(X)$ is the column when $Y=0$? But then by the same argument $\mathbb{P}(Y)$ is the column when $X=0$. Then we need $2a+c=1$ and $2b+c=1$, which implies $a=b$, but he does not require this.

Is there a way to retrieve "single distribution" from the discrete joint distribution table?

> Additionally, it will really appreciated if anyone could teach me how to compute $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$ given this table. Thank you!

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Since you tagged this "conditional expectation", I'll assume you have seen conditional probabilities and the law of total probability.  Use that in your reasoning to resolve your second question. Total probability applies -- think it through carefully. :-)

Comment: @nomen no..this exercise is before the conditional probability distribution.. so I don't know have this kind of knowledge. but now it is clear.

Comment: okay.  Then go back to the basic axioms of probability and look at the "sum rule" for mutually exclusive events.  That's what Siong used in his answer. For example, f Y is -1, it can't be 0, or 1.  So P(X = k) = P(X = k, Y=-1) + P(X = k, Y=0) + P(X = k, Y=1).

Comment: @nomen oh! Thank you so much for pointing out this direction. I will definitely look them up.

Comment: by the way, the distribution of X calculated in this way is called the "marginal distribution of X".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution

Comment: @nomen thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a joint distribution, we can compute the marginal distribution.

$$P(X=1) = P(X=1, Y=-1) + P(X=1, Y=0)+P(X=1, Y=1)=0+a+0=a$$

which is the sum of the first row.

$$P(Y=1) = P(X=1, Y=1) + P(X=0, Y=1) + P(X=-1, Y=1)=0+b+0=b$$

In general $$P(X=x) = \sum_y P(X=x, Y=y)$$

and $$P(Y=y) = \sum_x P(X=x, Y=y)$$

Since 
$$P(X=1, Y=1)=0$$ which was read off from the upper left corner, the condition that $a>0, b>0$ are stated to ensure that the product $ab$ can't be equal to $0$, which established the validity of the counter example.

$$E(Y|X=1)=1\cdot Pr(Y=1|X=1) + 0\cdot Pr(Y=0|X=1) - 1\cdot Pr(Y=-1|X=1)=0$$

Similarly

$$E(Y|X=-1)=1\cdot Pr(Y=1|X=-1) + 0\cdot Pr(Y=0|X=-1) - 1\cdot Pr(Y=-1|X=-1)=0$$

\begin{align}E(Y|X=0)&=1\cdot Pr(Y=1|X=0) + 0\cdot Pr(Y=0|X=0) - 1\cdot Pr(Y=-1|X=0) \\
&= \frac{b}{2b+c}+0 - \frac{b}{2b+c}\\&=0\end{align}

That is $E(Y|X)=0$ which actually can be read off since each row is symmetrical.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had no undergrad probability knowledge, directly going to PhD course. Now it is really really clear to me. Thank you!

Comment: Stackexchanges only allows me to give you bounty after 22 hours.. so let's wait for 22 hours...

Comment: One possible typo, do you mean $\mathbb{P}(Y=y_{0})=\sum_{x}\mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y_{0})$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical yeah theres a typo (using $Y= x$ instead of $Y = y$ in the answer's 4th equation). Your correction fits, but you could just use $y$ instead of $y_0$ as was probably intended.

Comment: yes, I made a typo, thanks for pointing that out.